# ASP.NET MVC. How to download many text files (pdf, docx, txt) and send to print?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to send many, difference text files to print one click on button in my WebApplication but the first I have to download this files from server.

How should I have to do?

Comment: You're going to need some client-side application for that.  A single web request can only download one file.  That file can be a `.zip` of all the files you need to send, but it's still up to the client to unpackage it.  And in the browser all you can do is open the print dialog for the user, you can't force it to actually print.

Comment: Or you could create one single file on the server and send that to the client.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send more than one file in the same response. It's programmatically feasible, but the browser will not be able to understand the response.

If you need to send several content in just one event (a click response, for example) it is better to compress the documents and send one .zip file. The other option is to response to different buttons, one per file.

The reason is that the HTTP only expects one kind of response, not two or more.